# Automatically redirecting to created page with PHP and mySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I am creating a simple forum for a class project, and while I'm sure this question has been asked before, it's kind of hard to search for something like this. basically I have a newthread.php page, (located here for convenience: http://pastebin.com/CjF4zyFk ) which is just a simple form created in dreamweaver (which is why its ugly). However, for some reason, no matter what I put in to the $insertGoTo statement, when I hit submit, it goes to the page that was created just prior to yours. So what I am wondering is does anyone know what I need to put into the goto statement that makes it go to the topic you just created? I could easily make it go to the topic page, or the home page, etc- but that would be kinda round about and ugly.

(and yes, I know that mySQL commands are being phased out because its unsafe and such, but, this is what I'm learning and this is what I've got for now:/)

edit: in an attempt to make it more "specific", here's a little code snippet

```
mysql_select_db($database_tj_forum, $tj_forum);
$Result1 = mysql_query($insertSQL, $tj_forum) or die(mysql_error());
$insertGoTo = "comments.php?threadID=".[what do i put here];
if (isset($_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'])) {
$insertGoTo .= (strpos($insertGoTo, '?')) ? "&" : "?";
$insertGoTo .= $_SERVER['QUERY_STRING'];
```

I just need help with determining what would best go where those brackets are. The only thing I can think of that would make sense to me would be to redirect it to the page that, in the database, would fit a where clause with a variable that represents the input title of the thread, and the username as determined by the session. However, that is what I do not understand how to do.

Comment: `I know that mySQL commands are being phased out because its unsafe and such, but, this is what I'm learning` - Shouldn't you take advantage of that knowledge? You know you shouldn't go ahead with mysql, but still are...It's so much easier to switch to a new API when you're just starting out than to do it when you've been using it for quite some time

Comment: the reason i'm not learning a new API is because this is for school as stated, and I have a deadline- and don't really have the time to go back and change the whole thing to a new API

Answer (score 0):

You already know not to use the `mysql_` functions so I won't comment on that. To fix your issue you just need to get the ID of the inserted item. PHP has a function called `mysql_insert_id` that will do that for you.

Just change that line to `$insertGoTo = "comments.php?threadID=" . mysql_insert_id();`

Should do the job.

Comment: you know, I saw this command at one point but I was skeptical to it being that easy. I feel kinda dumb- I was up so late last night I probably wasn't thinking straight. Thank you, I love you. I plan on learning mysqli or PDO this summer as my own thing, but I just needed this for my assignment

Comment: No worries! Definitely a good idea to learn something else when you have the time (always good to learn more, but in this case especially important). Good luck with it all.